# хранение определённого максимума для значений и самих значений в БД

Tags: c#, sql

Суть такая - мне надо хранить в базе данных (ms sql) 9 разных значений, они могут уменьшаться и увеличиваться (независимо друг от друга). НО мне также надо время от времени сбрасывать эти значения до изначального состояния.
Я подумал, что пожно хранить всё это в двух массивах, но оказалось, что массивы в бд хранить нельзя. А если создавать каждое поле, то получится 18 столбцов в бд.
Изначально я хотел сделать так - хранить все эти значения в виде одной строки (пример - "1 2 5 6 7.."), а когда надо просто парсить их и доставать значения.
Вопрос - насколько это костыль и как можно его обойти?

Comment: https://www.sql.ru/articles/mssql/03060701arraysandlistsinsqlserver.shtml - статья конечно старая, может и придумали что-то новое

Comment: Просмотрел статью по диагонали. Думаю, с тех пор придумали только сериализовать любой тип в json и хранить его прямо в blob - причем пошла это мода с монги, в которой такое хранение - обычное дело :-)

Comment: Да, вполне можно хранить значения в виде одной строки (и парсить для извлечения их). Когда-то раньше такой способ был нормой (потом быстродействие увеличилось, памяти стало больше и от него почти отказались). / А можно эти значения хранить в виде xml или json. В разных БД есть разные способы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что хранение значений в базе данных напоминает не записи последовательных значений в строку, а, скорее, запись значений в столбец, где рядом со значением находится его идентификатор. Обычно его называют primary key.

Примерно на SQL это выглядит так:

```
    insert into Table1 (id, val) values (1, 176)
```

Здесь  176 - значение, а 1 - это идентификатор, по котормоу можно это значение достатьь обратно из базы, примерно так:

```
    select val from Table1 where id = 1
```

При этом сама Table1 сотоит из двух столбцов - id и val

Если значение изменилось, и надо сохранить инфу об этом в базк - то в sql это будет как то так:

```
    update Table1 set val=177 where id=1
```

Дальше начинаются тонкости. Одно дело - это хранить "мгновеннное состояние" значений 9 переменных (для этого достаточно просто использовать id от1 до 9). Но иногда надо сохранить историю изменений - например, чтобы потом построить графики изменения температуры, измеренной 9 разными датчиками. Тогда - в таблицу надо добавить еще один столбец, время, и использовать только Insert - то есть, только добавлять данные.

Надеюсь, мой ответ поможет